# is there any way to get data from service to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am trying sending the data of file in chunks to web api through worker service. But chunks can not be received by web api, here is my code

Here is some code of worker service

```
int chunkSize = 100;

using (Stream streamx = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];


    int bytesRead = 0;
    long bytesToRead = streamx.Length;

    while (bytesToRead > 0)
    {
        int n = streamx.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);

        if (n == 0) break;

        // Let's resize the last incomplete buffer
        if (n != buffer.Length)
            Array.Resize(ref buffer, n);

        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        HttpContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        form.Add(byteContent, "fileByte");

        HttpResponseMessage response1 = null;
        try
        {
            response1 = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:15594/weatherforecast/PostData", form).Result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        var k = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        response = null;
        bytesRead += n;
        bytesToRead -= n;
    }
```

Here is some code of web api

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("PostData")]
public IActionResult PostData()
{
    var request = HttpContext.Request;
    
    var vals = request.Form.TryGetValue("fileByte", out StringValues sv).ToString();

    NameValueCollection vals2 = new NameValueCollection();
    int count = vals2.Count;
    string cv = null;
    foreach(var i in vals2)
    {
        cv += i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "*chunks can not be received by web api*"? I don't know specifically what you mean by that.

Comment: `PostData` impl. makes no sense whatsovever. How do you expect `vals2` to contain any data?

Comment: Here I send the httpcontent data to the web api but in weapi it receives null. can anyone give any idea to send httpcontent to webapi and how to receive that httpcontent by webapi

Answer (score 0):

Here I have solved the issue, basically I want to upload a file in chunks ,
Here the code of file uploading to webapi ,

int chunkSize = 1024

```
        using (Stream streamx = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];



            int bytesRead = 0;
            long bytesToRead = streamx.Length;



            while (bytesToRead > 0)
            {



                int n = streamx.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);



                if (n == 0) break;



                if (n != buffer.Length)
                    Array.Resize(ref buffer, n);



                MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
                multiContent.Add(bytes, "file", fi.Name);




                HttpResponseMessage response1 = null;
                try
                {
                    response1 = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:15594/weatherforecast/PostData", multiContent).Result;



                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }



                var k = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                response = null;



                bytesRead += n;
                bytesToRead -= n;



            }
        }
```

'''
here is code snippet of webapi

'''

[HttpPost]
[Route("PostData")]

```
    public IActionResult PostData()
    {​​​​​​​


        var form = Request.Form;
        foreach (var formFile in form.Files)
        {​​​​​​​


            var fileName = formFile.FileName;


            var savePath = Path.Combine(@"E:\Program\_210302_1WebApplication_API\_210302_1WebApplication_API\wwwroot", fileName);


            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Append))
            {​​​​​​​
                formFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }​​​​​​​
        }​​​​​​​
```

}​​​​​​​

'''